# Mongoose updateMany witd andWhere and orWhere?

Tags: mongodb

I am doing query update database mongoDB.
For example I have six item objects in the collection `product` (My actual data is a lot) :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('1232'),
    title: 'Product 1',
    order: 1,
    code: 'A',
    status: 'active'
}
{
    _id: ObjectId('4444'),
    title: 'Product 2',
    order: 2,
    code: 'B',
    status: 'active'
}
{
    _id: ObjectId('2232'),
    title: 'Product 3',
    order: 3,
    code: 'A'
    status: 'unActive'
}
{
    _id: ObjectId('55555'),
    title: 'Product 4',
    order: 4,
    code: 'C',
    status: 'active'
}
{
    _id: ObjectId('66666'),
    title: 'Product 5',
    order: 5,
    code: 'D',
    status: 'active'
}
{
    _id: ObjectId('2222'),
    title: 'Product 6',
    order: 6,
    code: 'C',
    status: 'active'
}
```

Now I want to update `code` using query :

- If `status = active` .
- If `code = A` it will be replaced with `A1`.
- If `code = B` => `B1`.
- If `code = C` => `C1`.
- If `code = D` => `D1`

And here is the query I made:

```
db.getCollection('product').updateMany({'code': 'A'}, {$set: {'code': 'A1'}})
```

But I can only replace only with where condition. How to use andWhere or orWhere to change the value of `code`. Please give me your opinion so that I can fix this problem. Thank you. I'm new to MongoDb, so I'm having a hard time. Hope everyone understands.

Comment: what do you mean by andWhere , orWhere. don't have it in mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the aggregation pipeline with MongoDB update. You can find an example for a conditional update with [`$switch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#mongodb-expression-exp.-switch) statement in the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/#example-3)

```js
db.getCollection('product').updateMany({status:'active'}, [
     { $set: { code: { $switch: {
                           branches: [
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$code", "A"] }, then: "A1" },
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$code", "B"] }, then: "B1" },
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$code", "C"] }, then: "C1" },
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$code", "D"] }, then: "D1" }
                           ],
                           default: ""  //can remove if switch satisfy at least 1 condition above
     } } } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qiCy7lYCkf_)

Comment: Thank @cmgchess. I have one more case I need your help with. Like the example above. In each object I have `status = active` and `status = unActive` fields. Now I want to add the condition that objects with `status = active` update `code`. Can you help me? Let me update the question again

Comment: @Miedkes `updateMany({status:'active'}, [....` ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-to-one mapping like A -> A1, B -> B1, etc. Then you don't need any filters, you can simply do it like this, concatenating your current `code` with `1`:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      code: {
        $concat: [
          "$code",
          "1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/clmIaFTS5HL)